# File Encryption Using RSA

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to implement RSA algorithm. I want to encrypt an image. The problem is when the decrypt is finished, the file can't be read. I don't know where is the problem exactly. This is the implementation of RSA:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class RSA {
private BigInteger p;
private BigInteger q;
private BigInteger N;
private BigInteger phi;
private BigInteger e;
private BigInteger d;
private int bitlength = 1024;

private Random r;
 public RSA() {
    r = new Random();
    p = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength, r);
    q = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength, r);
    N = p.multiply(q);

    phi =   p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
    e = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength/2, r);
    System.out.println("e : "+e);

    while (phi.gcd(e).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0 && e.compareTo(phi) < 0 ) {
        e.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
   d = e.modInverse(phi); 
    }
```

This is the main method:

```
 public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
       {

RSA rsa = new RSA();   

      byte[] bytesImage= rsa.readBytesFromFile(new File(
            "F:\\calla.jpg"));
      //readBytesFromFile: method to read file as bytes


 byte[] encrypted = rsa.encrypt(bytesImage);    
     writeBytesToFile(new File(
            "F:\\encryptedcalla.jpg"),encrypted );
  //writeBytesToFile: method to write as bytes

// decrypt
    byte[] decrypted = rsa.decrypt(encrypted); 
     writeBytesToFile(new File(
            "F:\\decryptedcalla.jpg"),decrypted );


}
```

This is the method of encryption:

```
    // Encrypt image
 public byte[] encrypt(byte[] image) {   
     byte[] encryptedImage = new byte[image.length];
    for (int i =0 ; i< image.length; i++){
        encryptedImage[i]= (BigInteger.valueOf(image[i])).modPow(e, N).byteValue(); 

     }   
      return encryptedImage;
}
```

This is the method of decryption:

```
 public byte[] decrypt(byte[] image) {   
    byte[] decryptedImage = new byte[image.length];
    for (int i =0 ; i< image.length; i++){
        decryptedImage[i]= (BigInteger.valueOf(image[i])).modPow(d, N).byteValue();

     } 

     return decryptedImage;

}
```

The methods of reading and writing are described here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Readfiletobytearrayandsavebytearraytofile.htm

Comment: I do have to ask why you're writing your own crypto code. If it's not for a toy project where the image decryption is just an excuse to try writing crypto, I strongly recommend using the (far more secure) pre-written implementations.

Comment: I have to test it by my implementation.

Comment: Uh, test what, exactly?

Comment: I would encrypt with the standard Java Cipher class and test your decryption code against that, and then test that your encryption code has the same result as the Java Cipher class produces. Is your code *really* RSA encryption? Doesn't look like it to me.

Comment: I would bet that modPow returns a value bigger than 255.

Comment: Also, encrypting byte-by-byte is insecure (it's equivalent to a substitution cipher, which fails pretty badly against known-plaintext attacks, and fails completely against chosen-plaintext attacks)

Comment: #Nathan Tuggy: Test how can I encrypt and decrypt image using RSA algorithm.

Comment: # EJP: What do you mean by really RSA encryption?

Comment: # immibis: I'm doing byte-by-byte because it said that asymmetric encryption is only designed for encrypting data smaller than it's key size.

Comment: I think the problem is the calculation of the public key.

Comment: @Newbie If *you* don't know what is meant by 'really RSA encryption', you can't possibly be *implementing* RSA encryption.

Comment: @EJP I do know the algorithm, but I don't know what you mean by really RSA.

Comment: I've found the problem is here: encryptedImage[i]= (BigInteger.valueOf(image[i])).modPow(e, N).byteValue();

Comment: The problem occurs when converting BigInteger to Byte. Any suggestion about how can I overcome that?

Comment: 1) Use hybrid encryption 2) Textbook RSA is completely broken.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, as you say, in this step:

```
encryptedImage[i]= (BigInteger.valueOf(image[i])).modPow(e, N).byteValue();
```

The problem is, that `modPow()` is returning a 1024-bit number, and you are trying to stuff that into an 8-bit byte.  You can't do that without losing some information, and if you lose *any* information, then you won't be able to decrypt the message.

RSA is *mathematical* cryptography:  You have to encode your message as a number, then you encrypt by computing a function that turns that number into a different number (that's the `modPow(e, N)`).  Then you have to transmit the *whole* encrypted message number.

The recipient of the message takes the encrypted number and runs it through the decryption function `modPow(d, N)` which should give back the original number, and then that can be transformed back into the original message.

But the recipient has to get the whole 1024-bit number in order for the decryption to work.

If you use RSA to encrypt each individual byte of the image, then for each byte in to the encryption algorithm, you will have to send a 1024-bit packet to the recipient.  Then the recipient can decrypt that packet, and extract the original byte.

Or, you could encrypt two bytes at a time, or ten bytes, or 100 bytes;  but what you can't do is make the "packets" any smaller than 1024 bits.

Comment: If you mean by this *what you can't do is make the "packets" any smaller than 1024 bits* that the message for a single RSA invokation has to be bigger than 1024-bit, then it will be impossible to recover the message back. It has to be exactly 1024-bit, but the value has to be smaller than *N*. That is why **padding** is used with the first byte set to 0x00 and filled up to 1024-bit.

Comment: @james large As I understood from your answer I've changed the encryption and decryption methods:
This is the encryption method:
'  public BigInteger[] encrypt (byte[] image){
           BigInteger[] encryptedImage = new BigInteger[image.length];
         for (int i =0 ; i< image.length; i++){
            encryptedImage[i]= (BigInteger.valueOf(image[i])).modPow(e, N); 

         }   

        return encryptedImage;
    }
      '

Comment: @ArtjomB. You're right.  I did not explain padding when I said "encode your message as a number".  The idea I was trying to get across was that, at its heart, the RSA algorithms doesn't encrypt _messages_, it encrypts _numbers_, and you can't just send part of the encrypted number and expect to recover part of the original at the other end.  You have to send the whole number.  Somebody who knows that much should be able to figure out the necessity of padding and the details of converting between plaintext and numbers and ciphertext and vice versa.

Comment: So, the encryption method will take array of bytes and return array of BigInteger. While decryption method will take array of BigInteger and return array of byte which should be the original bytes.

Comment: Encrypt method:

`public BigInteger[] encrypt (byte[] image){
  BigInteger[] encryptedImage = new BigInteger[image.length]; 
  for (int i =0 ; i< image.length; i++){ 
   encryptedImage[i]=  (BigInteger.valueOf(image[i])).modPow(e, N);
    }
 return encryptedImage; }`

Decrypt method:

`public byte[] decrypt(BigInteger[] image) {   
        byte[] decryptedImage = new byte[image.length];
         for (int i =0 ; i< image.length; i++){
            decryptedImage[i]= (image[i]).modPow(d, N).byteValue();
         }
          return decryptedImage;      
    }`

It should return the original bytes.

Comment: @Newbieprogrammer  A practical system would have to work out some details of how to transmit an array of BigIntegers from the sender to the receiver.  Consider reading some of the PKCS standards published by RSA Data Security to learn what practical crypto systems look like:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1

Comment: @jameslarge Before the transmission, I want to test it on my computer. When I did the last update, the result is not the original bytes!

Comment: I've found similar problem here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507488/convert-arbitrary-size-of-byte-to-biginteger-and-then-safely-convert-back-to)
Which is asked by @PatlaDJ but I couldn't figure out what is the solution.

Comment: Hint: RSA doesn't work on negative numbers either, and bytes in Java are signed.